# Bibtex - Customize .bst file so that misc entry title are in italics

Tags: bibtex, chicago-style

I have customized a `.bst` file for my purposes, but I can't figure out how to format the title of just the `misc` entries, so that it is displayed in italics.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
I cite this sources \citep{company}.

\bibliographystyle{chicago-annote-copy}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\end{document}
```

This is in my `bibliography.bib` file:

```
@Misc{company,
author       = {{Company}},
title        = {Title in italics},
howpublished = {Available from : some url },
year         = {2000},
note         = {[Accessed 01 August 2017]},
}
```

And here you can find my [`.bst` file](https://github.com/AWi-001/MWE.git)

I hope it's clear what I am trying to achieve. Otherwise please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to edit the `FUNCTION {misc}`. The Formatting of the title is done by the `format.title` function, then the `title` is put on the stack. So you just have to call `emphasize` (already defined in the .bst file) to add `\em{` `}` to the title:

```
FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  output.year.check
  title howpublished new.block.checkb
  format.title emphasize output       % Added emphasize here
  new.block
  institution "institution" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished output
  new.block
  note output
  fin.entry
  format.annote write$
}
```

(this starts at the line 1259 of your `chicago-annote-copy`)